# some radio buttons not able to be selected in template

Tags: backbone.js

I'm making a backbone quiz app that uses the question_template below to append questions into a div. Once the first question is answered, the second question is appended, pushing the first one below, etc. Once it gets to the third question, the html radio buttons break. I am not able to select the top button (answer red) for the third question. However, once the fourth question is loaded, and the third question gets pushed down, I am able to select the red button for the third question (although you can't submit anymore because submit becomes disabled by design after questions been answered). In the fourth question, I can't select either of the top two radio buttons. I'm having the same problem in every browser. I've posted an image of the screen with the 3rd and 4th question loaded. I'm wondering if there's something in this template that might explain why I'm having a problem.

**Update:** before you read everything, it might help to know that the problem with the radio buttons only happens if I render the questions to div using prepend i.e. $('this.el').prepend, which I want to do to add the questions to the top. If I use append $('this.el').append...the radio buttons work fine, but it doesn't allow me to add new questions to the top.

Code.
    ![

```
<fieldset id="qbquestion">
    <legend>{{= question }}</legend>
      <ul>
    {{ _.each(answers, function(answer) { }}

<li><input type="radio" name="{{= question }}" value="{{= answer  }}"/> <label for="{{= answer  }}">{{= answer  }}</label></li>

{{ }); }}
    </ul>

</fieldset>

      <input type="button" class="action_button" value="Submit" id="answer">

</script>][1]
```

Image explanation

For the question, "What is M's favorite color" i'm not able to select the 'red' button until it's been pushed down. For the top question, I'm not able to select either of the top two buttons "pink" or "purp". There are only four questions in the database right now.

[image]

Update
This is the css styles for the "red" radio button (the one that can't be selected) of the question "What is M's favorite color". The styles are the same if I inspect a different radio button.

[image]

Update
the html of the question, "what is M's favorite color"[image]

**QuestionView**Update, in the render function, if I use $('this.el').append...then the resulting radio buttons work. However, I wanted to do `$('this.el').prepend` so the new questions added to the top. If I use prepend, certain radio buttons don't work.

```
var QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".east"), 
    initialize: function(){


    _.bindAll(this);
    this.compTemplates();
        this.model.bind("gameStartedEvent", this.render, this); 
    this.model.bind("guessCheckedEvent", this.nextQuestion, this);
    this.model.bind("nextQuestionReady", this.render, this);
    },

  events: {
      'click #answer': 'checkAnswer'

    },

  nextQuestion: function(){
    this.model.nextQuestion();
  },
  checkAnswer: function(e){
    $('#answer').attr("disabled", true);
    var selected = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
    var answer = selected.val();
    this.model.set({guess: answer});
     this.model.check();

  },
  compTemplates: function(){
    console.log("comp Templates in question view");
    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate : /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
        escape : /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
         };
    var template = $('#question_template').html();

    this.template = _.template(template);


  },

    render: function(response){

    var question = response.question; 
    var answers = response.answers;
    var link = response.link;
    this.correctanswer = response.correctanswer;

 $(this.el).append(this.template({ question: question, answers: answers, link: link})); 


    }


 });
```

Comment: How are you trying to select the radio buttons? By clicking on the `<input>` or the `<label>`?

Comment: @muistooshort I'm only able to select at all by clicking the input (the round button) I can't click on any of the labels ("red" "green" etc). Is there a way to make the labels selectable?

Comment: Your `for` attributes should match the `id` attributes of your radio buttons (http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/label.html). Any chance of seeing a demo or at least the HTML that comes out? You might be producing broken HTML.

Comment: @muistooshort ok, I gave the radio buttons a matching id, now I can select the labels, but I still can't select "red" for the third question etc. I posted the html (before adding the radio buttons id) with the css.

Comment: That should work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/S2TK5/). What else is going on? A functional demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would probably make the problem obvious.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks. a little more info with some progress. I posted the Question view. In render, I now use $('this.el').append and all the resulting radio buttons work. However, I want to use $('this.el').prepend so that the new questions are added at the top, pushing the others down. If I use prepend, some of the radio buttons don't work.  It's too complex to set up a demo...Do you know another way to add the new questions to the top without using prepend?

Comment: Are you ending up with multiple elements with `id="answer"`? That's not only invalid HTML but can cause various odd things to happen, that  could explain the "`append` works but `prepend` doesn't" strangeness.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a number of things, but unfortunately I'm not sure which one fixed the problem.  One, I stopped using multiple elements with the same id, as @mu is too short suggested. I also changed some of the positional styles on the containing elements, because, since only the third and fourth questions were affected, it seemed to be a problem related to the amount of space allocated to the questions. Sorry, I'm crap at css and can't explain more.  I also created a new view `new QuestionView();` for each question rather than using the same one over again, however, I think it was a problem caused solely by the css.